# How is "git pull" done with the git2-rs Rust crate?

Tags: git, rust, pull, libgit2

I'm using [git2-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs) to implement some standard git functionality in a Rust application. I've been reading up on git internals and understand that at a high level "git pull" is a "git fetch" followed by a "git merge", but am still having trouble understanding how to make it work with git2-rs. There is a discussion on an issue [here](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs/issues/129) where it's agreed that a git2-rs "git pull" example would be nice, but one was never created. There is an example of doing a hard reset in that discussion, but I want to avoid overwriting local changes (thus the merge). I have been unable to find an example in any other codebases that use git2-rs as well.

The "git reset" example [here](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs/issues/129#issuecomment-302979206) shows how to get an OID after a fetch I think, but the merge function takes an [AnnotatedCommit](https://docs.rs/git2/0.8.0/git2/struct.AnnotatedCommit.html), and I'm not sure how to convert between the two, or even if that's the right direction to go.

Comment: For unknow reason, `git2-rs` doesn't bind [`git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead()`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/annotated/git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead), I suggest you open an issue on github.

Comment: So, I've found 
`let reference = repo.find_reference("FETCH_HEAD")?;
    let fetch_head_commit = repo.reference_to_annotated_commit(&reference)?;
`
but `repo.merge(&[&fetch_head_commit], None, None)?;` seems to miss a commit? See also [reset to fetched](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs/issues/129#issuecomment-302979206)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```rust
        let our_commit = find_last_commit()?;
        let reference = repo.find_reference("FETCH_HEAD")?;
        let their_commit = reference.peel_to_commit()?;
        let _index = repo
                .merge_commits(&our_commit, &their_commit, Some(&MergeOptions::new()))?;
```

using

```rust
   pub fn find_last_commit(repo: &Repository) -> Result<Commit, RepoError> {
        let obj = repo.head()?.resolve()?.peel(ObjectType::Commit)?;
        match obj.into_commit() {
            Ok(c) => Ok(c),
            _ => Err(RepoError::new("commit error")),
        }
    }
```