# How to perform "git pull" with the Rust git2 crate?

Tags: git, rust, pull, libgit2

The git2 crate doesn't have direct way to perform "git pull" action.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100789/how-is-git-pull-done-with-the-git2-rs-rust-crate) and tried to do it the same way ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=210897a16bf49de9bb797fe69658ec25)):

```
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{stderr, stdout, Write};
use std::path::Path;

use git2::{Commit, Error, Index, MergeOptions, ObjectType, Repository, ResetType};

struct Repo {
    url: &'static str,
    path: &'static str,
    branch: &'static str,
}

impl Repo {
    fn reset(&self, path: &Path) {
        let repo = match Repository::open(path) {
            Ok(repo) => repo,
            Err(e) => panic!("Failed to open: {}", e),
        };
        repo.reset(
            &repo.revparse_single("HEAD").unwrap(),
            ResetType::Hard,
            None,
        )
        .unwrap();
    }

    fn clone(&self) {
        let repo = match Repository::clone(self.url, self.path) {
            Ok(repo) => repo,
            Err(e) => panic!("failed to init: {}", e),
        };
    }

    fn find_last_commit<'repo>(&self, repo: &'repo Repository) -> Result<Commit<'repo>, Error> {
        let obj = repo.head()?.resolve()?.peel(ObjectType::Commit)?;
        match obj.into_commit() {
            Ok(c) => Ok(c),
            _ => Err(Error::from_str("commit error")),
        }
    }

    fn pull(&self, path: &Path) -> Result<Index, Error> {
        let repo = Repository::open(path)?;

        repo.find_remote("origin")?
            .fetch(&[self.branch], None, None)?;

        let last_commit = self.find_last_commit(&repo)?;
        let reference = repo.find_reference("FETCH_HEAD")?;
        let fetched_commit = reference.peel_to_commit()?;
        let index =
            repo.merge_commits(&last_commit, &fetched_commit, Some(&MergeOptions::new()))?;

        return Ok(index);
    }

    pub fn check(&self) {
        let repo_path = Path::new(self.path);

        if !repo_path.exists() {
            self.clone();
            return;
        }

        if repo_path.exists() && repo_path.is_dir() {
            self.reset(repo_path);
            let idx = match self.pull(repo_path) {
                Ok(idx) => idx,
                Err(e) => panic!("Failed to pull: {}", e),
            };
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let currencies = Repo {
        url: "https://github.com/datasets/currency-codes",
        path: "./resources/currency-codes",
        branch: "master",
    };

    currencies.check();
}
```

But while *clone* and *reset* work, it looks like *pull* doesn't.

What am I do wrong?

Comment: Can you clearly state what "doesn't work" means? What do you *expect* to happen and what *actually* happens?

Comment: I expect that changes from external repository will be pulled to local repository. Exactely the same way as i type "git pull" inthe console. But after I run this code *nothing* changed in local repo at all.

Comment: It does work, doesn't it?

Comment: @edwardw I tried it on two systems Win10 and Ubuntu 18.10. Steps
1) Build once and get repo cloned.
2) Perform "*git reset --hard HEAD^^^*" in repo. Check that HEAD is changed. 3) Run "*cargo build*" one more time. 4) Check result: HEAD still in same position. 5) Double-check it by run "*git pull*" manually - HEAD is changed on the same position as after #1. So, this code and git pull definitely works different way.

Comment: @Argentumbolo "cargo build" does not run anything, try "cargo run"

Comment: @JussiKukkonen I forget to mention - this code is part of "**build.rs**". So it works at "**cargo build**".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `git2-rs` repo does have [a pending PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/pull/427) which adds a pull example. I adapted it a bit here to show how to do a fast-forward since that's what you are looking for:

```rust
fn fast_forward(&self, path: &Path) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let repo = Repository::open(path)?;

    repo.find_remote("origin")?
        .fetch(&[self.branch], None, None)?;

    let fetch_head = repo.find_reference("FETCH_HEAD")?;
    let fetch_commit = repo.reference_to_annotated_commit(&fetch_head)?;
    let analysis = repo.merge_analysis(&[&fetch_commit])?;
    if analysis.0.is_up_to_date() {
        Ok(())
    } else if analysis.0.is_fast_forward() {
        let refname = format!("refs/heads/{}", self.branch);
        let mut reference = repo.find_reference(&refname)?;
        reference.set_target(fetch_commit.id(), "Fast-Forward")?;
        repo.set_head(&refname)?;
        repo.checkout_head(Some(git2::build::CheckoutBuilder::default().force()))
    } else {
        Err(Error::from_str("Fast-forward only!"))
    }
}

pub fn check(&self) {
    ...
    if repo_path.exists() && repo_path.is_dir() {
        self.reset(repo_path);
        if let Err(e) = self.fast_forward(repo_path) {
            panic!("Failed to pull: {}", e)
        }
    }
}
```

The credit is original author's of course. You can also check it out for nontrivial merge case, i.e. when the local tree is dirty.

Comment: Thank you. I added an **analysis.0.is_up_to_date()** branch but it's obviously what I looked for.

Comment: @Argentumbolo good catch. I updated the code snippet to cover that as well.